# Log4net doesn't produce a log file when my project is deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I have log4net enabled and it writes log files when I test in Visual Studio.

However it does not log files when I deploy to IIS on my machine.

I believe it's permission related.

I am not sure what permissions I would need to set.

In my web.config I set the file path at:

```
 <param name="File" value="C:\MyFolder\LogFiles\MySite_Debug.log" />
```

For permissions I added IUSR and IIS and gave it read/write to my LogFiles folder.

EDIT:
I've added to the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

also in my Global.asax I have

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In the application_strat method..

I still can't get this to log when running in IIS 7.5

EDIT 2:

I looked at this link
[App Pool Link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

My app pool identity is set to: ApplicationPoolIdentity.

 I can't resolve "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" or "AppPoolIdentity" when I go to set securtiy on my folder.

Comment: Try enabling log4net internal logging and see whether that helps

Comment: The account that the hosting Application Pool is running as needs permission to write to the folder (note log4net will not create folders for you)

Comment: @Shyju - I had previously tried that and do not see a log

Comment: @stuartd Since this is a local test on my machine the folders are already in place.  The only thing that I did was to delete any of the log files that I create (when running from VS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't resolve the user, make sure you are looking on your local machine. The ApplicationPoolIdentity is a local user. So you need to select at Locations localhost when setting permissions.